# How to check jquery is working and Jquery.min.js file has loaded successfully

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am getting a big issue that most of the time my code works properly but sometime when i insert data into database it returns output as json. get data as json.

Most of the time i get the "success" in response, that is retured by json but some time i get complete json in output.

I have two pages -

1. index.php page - Here i get response returned by registration.php page as json
2. and second is registration.php - Here i have code to insert data into database, and it works fine and most of time returns json response as "success".

But some time The page that insert data into database (registration.php) stops working and show complete json as output.

**and this is js file**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I think whenever jquery(JS) file dosn't loads completely, it stops working.

**So now my question is how to check that our jquery(JS) file has loaded successfuly,
before submit form or before processing so that it can't stop working and always respond output.
Or is there any other resone of stop responding.**

Comment: What event is that AJAX call being made under?

Comment: Use `ready` event -- https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: You need to tell us what triggers the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: This is complete code now plese tell me silution...

I think whenever jquery-3.5.0.min.js dosn't loads properly it stops woring

So please tell me how to check jquery-3.5.0.min.js has loaded successfuly

Comment: @PradyumnaRajora please edit the question to include that code. It's almost unreadable in a comment

Comment: @ RoryMcCrossan now please check

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

})
```

Like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'regstriation.php',
    data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var ayz = obj.message;
    $('#response').text(ayz);
    if(ayz == "success")
    {   
         window.location="https://www.example.com/";
    }
    })
    .fail(function(){
    alert( "Posting failed." );
    });
    return false;

})
```

Comment: If you look at the OPs comment under the question, they're already doing that

Comment: I am newbie in jquery, javascript and php so please tell me why some time i get json as output.

i think whenever jquery.min.js dosn't load it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click from the web page and go to view the source code.  Then click on the href link of the script, if you see the jquery code it means it's good otherwise it means you didn't import the code correctly.

Comment: Most of time i am getting output - "success", but why some time i get json as output. "registration.php" stops and shows json as output. i think whenever jquery.min.js dosn't load it happens.

I am newbie in jquery, javascript and php so please help me.